# i want display category page like in image but cant display as per my requirement

Tags: php, html, css

[image: i want my output like this]

[image: im getting output like this]

I want to display categories like the image above, but i am getting output like the 2nd image , my code is given below, please go through it

**This is my View page code shown here **

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <?php foreach ($MoreListMenuLevel1 as $menu1) { ?>
                <?php if (count($this->Categories_model->listsector1($menu1->id)) > 0) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="main-category-width">

                        <h4><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/onSectorClick1?id=<?php echo $menu1->id; ?>&name=<?php echo $menu1->sub1_category_name; ?>"><?php echo $menu1->sub1_category_name; ?></a></h4>

                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($this->Categories_model->Morelistsector2($menu1->id) as $menu2) { ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/onSectorClick2?id=<?php echo $menu2->id; ?>&name=<?php echo $menu2->sub2_category_name; ?>"> <?php echo ucwords($menu2->sub2_category_name); ?></a></li>
                            <?php } ?> 
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
            ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

**This is My CSS code shown here**

```
#modal-nav-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 70px 50px;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main-category-width {
    width: 19%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1% auto;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.main-category-width h4 a {
    color: #f43a43;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
.main-category-width ul li {
    padding: 7px;
}
.main-category-width ul li a {
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: Really? you want to display categories like shown in image ,but getting output as shown in image ? which image?

Comment: like first image

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solutions [Masonry Cascading grid layout library](https://masonry.desandro.com/#getting-started).

Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It works by placing elements in optimal position based on available vertical space, sort of like a mason fitting stones in a wall. You’ve probably seen it in use all over the Internet.

You can go with this. Check the link above.

Comment: Actually i am using bootstrap grid system

Comment: You can use Masonry layouts with Bootstrap grid system. Check the [link](https://masonry.desandro.com/extras.html#bootstrap) again. It works with bootstrap fine.

Comment: I want CDN links for css and js